# Using ffmpeg in Powershell

Tags: powershell, ffmpeg, converters

Can't find much information on this, as I believe it's a pretty noobish problem and there aren't really any tutorials on it. Can anyone explain how I can use ffmpeg in a powershell script? I downloaded ffmpeg and I have the path to ffmpeg.exe. Shouldn't I be able to do something like this?

```
"C:\path\ffmpeg.exe" -i stuff.mp3 stuff.wav
```

It returns an error message along the lines of -i not being a recognized parameter. Am I missing something pretty basic here? Thanks for any help. I'm trying to convert some audio files between .wav, .mp3. and .flac, and if anyone has any better suggestions than ffmpeg then please let me know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My prefered way is the [& operator](http://ss64.com/ps/call.html). Example:

```
& "C:\path\ffmpeg.exe" -i stuff.mp3 stuff.wav
```

Another alternatives:
http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/7703.powershell-running-executables.aspx

Comment: Hey look at that it worked! Thanks for the tip. My extremely limited understanding suggests that the & operator forces the entire line to go to the target, rather than looking at the path, then getting confused by a "-i" right after it and dropping the error I had. Thanks again!